# JS Rollover resizing in Chrome upon Rollover exit

Tags: javascript, html, rollover

I have a javascript rollover that works in other browsers, once I use Chrome to rollover it, upon exiting it resizes to an absurdly small size.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('<img />',{ src: 'images/image.gif'});
$(function() {
    $("#logohover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/image.gif");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/image.svg");
        }                         
    );                  
});
```

```
<img id="logohover" src="images/image.svg" width="50" height="50" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've found this [bug in Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82487).  Right now Webkit based browsers don't 100% support scaling SVGs.

Your best bet here will be to set the `width` and `height` properties in the `<svg>` tag itself (plus maybe the [`viewbox` and `preserveAspectRatio`](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/inkscape/+spec/allow-browser-resizing), I don't know if that's necessary) then scale the `<img>` tag using percentages.

In the SVG file:

```
<svg
    ...
    width="50"
    height="50"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    viewBox="0 0 50 50"
    ...
>
```

In the HTML:

```
<img id="logohover" src="images/image.svg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```